# Dash callback active cell only on specific column

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I am using the `callback` as below to open a modal when clicking on any cell in my Dash DataTable. However, instead of every cell opening the modal, I only want the modal to open when I click on a cell in the first column. Any tips on how to apply this `callback` only to the active cells in the first column?

```
@app.callback(Output('modal', 'is_open'),
              [Input('Data_Table', 'active_cell'),
               Input('close', 'n_clicks')],
              [State("modal", "is_open")])
def toggle_modal(n1, n2, is_open):
    if n1 or n2:
        return not is_open
    return is_open
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the position of the active cell in data tables like this:

```py
active_cell['column'] # column number (int)
active_cell['row'] # row number (int)
active_cell['column_id'] # column name (str)
```

Here's a full working example where the value of a cell from only the first column is returned in the modal when that cell is clicked:

```py
from dash import Dash, html, Input, Output, State, dash_table, no_update
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/solar.csv')

app = Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

modal = html.Div(
    [
        dbc.Modal(
            [
                dbc.ModalHeader(dbc.ModalTitle("Header")),
                dbc.ModalBody(id='modal-body'),
                dbc.ModalFooter(
                    dbc.Button(
                        "Close", id="close", className="ms-auto", n_clicks=0
                    )
                ),
            ],
            id="modal",
            is_open=False,
        ),
    ]
)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        modal,
        dash_table.DataTable(id='datatable',data=df.to_dict('records'), columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns])

    ]
)

@app.callback(
    [Output('modal','is_open'),Output('modal-body','children')],
    Input('datatable','active_cell'),
    State("modal", "is_open")

)
def open_modal(active_cell,is_open):
    if active_cell['column'] == 0:
        return [not is_open, df[active_cell['column_id']][active_cell['row']]]
    return [no_update,no_update]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```